# EF Core 3 - One-To-Many Relationship is not populating

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've got 2 models - User and Order.
A User has many orders and a order has one user.

```cs
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new List<Order>();
}
```

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

My database provider is MySQL, so I'm using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.

The problem is that the Orders property is always empty (or null without the property initializer).
I've tried playing around with ForeignKey and InversionProperty, but it doesn't help.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you annotating the Orders as being a HasMany using Fluent?

Comment: What's your query? You should `Include` Orders.

Comment: I tried to do so, but it doesn't do anything either. I thought using Fluent would be optional here though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the Order.User and User.Orders populated you need to call .Include(). For example:

```
this.databaseContext.Orders.Include(order => order.User).Where(...);
this.databaseContext.Users.Include(user => user.Orders).Where(...);
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

**Edit:** As seeing the comments under the question I think you have problem with setting up the relation between the two classes. In your context you should setup the relations. Here is an example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .HasOne(_ => _.User)
        .WithMany(_ => _.Orders)
        .HasForeignKey(_ => _.UserId);
}
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: Thanks! Include was the part which I honestly didn't try reading all the docs yesterday. I thought this wasn't needed, but it works now.

Comment: Saw your edit. Putting Include in the constructor of the AppDbContext did it for me, but now its kind of an random thing. In some occasions after reloads the list is still null. Restarting ASP.NET Core fixes it.

Comment: You shouldn't put Include in the constructor. You need to put include before every data retrieval, or you can setup lazy loading. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading

Comment: You're right. I looked into lazy binding after writing the comment and it solved it for me. Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: Happy to help! :D

Answer (score 0):

A better solution than using .Include() every time you pull something from the DB would be, in my opinion, enabling lazy loading in your Program.cs file.

You'll need to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies, and then you can just

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(optionsBuilder=>
{
            optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                          .UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration["PostgreConnectionString"]);
});
```